# how to call thingspeak api in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

i want to call thingspeak rest api and want to show the value in html page. im getting the value as undefined.

code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

     var response;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/channelid/fields/field1/last?api_key=key',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        format: 'json'
      },
      success: function(response) {
      response = response.field1;
      },
      error: function() {
        $('#errors').text("There was an error processing your request. Please try again.");
      }
    });

    document.getElementById("field1").innerHTML=response;
});
    </script>
```

api response data

```
{response = {created_at: "2018-03-28T09:36:48Z", entry_id: 2476, field1: "0}
```

Comment: This API is absolutely unknown to me, but I easilly found their [documention](https://www.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/readdata.html) where it says that a `channel id` is required... And it seems that it is missing in your `data`.

Comment: while debugging im getting the value , but i need the field1 value.

Comment: Have you tryed `alert(response.field1);`?

Comment: yes im getting the value in the response.field1, but im not able to show that data in the page due to scope issue

Comment: In the success callback: `$("someExistingElement").text(response.field1);`

Answer (score 2):

Following the API docs (https://www.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/readlastfieldentry.html) I found the response if you wanna get the text result you should fix your method. The new method should be something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/147878/fields/field1/last.txt?api_key=S4O9F5QP5QC',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        format: 'text'
      },
      success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
      },
      error: function() {
        $('#errors').text("There was an error processing your request. Please try again.");
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you believe that you're using the api in the correct way, as you can see in api response data that you mentioned, there is no "text" key, so you get undefined when you try to access response.text
if you want to convert the response to string format, you should use JSON.stringify(response)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/channelid/fields/field1/last?api_key=ur_app_key',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        format: 'json'
      },
      success: function(response) {
      $("#field1").text(response.field1);
      },
      error: function() {
        $('#errors').text("There was an error processing your request. Please try again.");
      }
    });
});
    </script>
```